# Having bad time with query

Tags: sql

portion of my query works except that it still show double my cpl_cli_prt_no often I just want it add show it once and sum inl_ship_qty like

```
#1 100000 quantity x50
```

instead of

```
#1 100000 quantity x20
#2 100000 quantity x30
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT  cpl_cli_prt_no
                ,SUM(inl_ship_qty)
                ,inl_price 
FROM invoicing_line 
WHERE (inl_ship_date >= @firstDate AND inl_ship_date <= @secondDate) 
AND cpl_cli_prt_no!='' 
GROUP BY cpl_cli_prt_no,inl_ship_qty,inl_price 
ORDER BY cpl_cli_prt_no ASC
```

Comment: you are grouping by inl_ship_qty, so it will not combine rows with different quantities

Comment: thanks for the information.

Comment: This query makes no sense.  Why are you comparing a column with the name of "date" to a variable with "name"?

Comment: edited productname to date even if it doesn't matter in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT may cause you to lose data. You probably don't want that.
The problem is you included the quantity in your GROUP statement. So, if multiple invoices contain the same part and price but different quantities, they will be shown separately. If you want to sum the quantity, remove it from your GROUP:

```
SELECT cpl_cli_prt_no,SUM(inl_ship_qty),inl_price FROM invoicing_line
WHERE (inl_ship_date >= @productName AND inl_ship_date <= @productName1) AND
cpl_cli_prt_no!='' GROUP BY cpl_cli_prt_no,inl_price
ORDER BY cpl_cli_prt_no ASC
```

Comment: thank you it's working I still get double value but it's because of the price which is different.

Comment: you should not get an error. You have a group function on the inl_ship_qty so it should not be in group list. Was the error before you added the SUM? Without SUM it may have resulted in error